# Why does an image appear blurry on a hdpi screen[running android] when it has been alloted the max possible pixels?

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface, user-experience, sketchup

I want to put **a 40 X 40 DP icon** somewhere on my app's screen. Now according to the ratio (3:4:6:8:12:16) of 6 different logical buckets, I **have provided an icon(.png file) with different sizes in 6 different drawable folders**.

In my case, the icon sizes must be *"MDPI = 40 X 40 PX, HDPI = 60 X 60 PX, XHDPI = 80 X 80 PX and so on" to maintain the same quality across devices at 40 X 40 DP.*

After doing so, I'm ***testing the app on a device with an HDPI screen***, which means it should look into the "drawable-HDPI" folder and render an image that basically fills up all the pixels (60 px in a space that has 60px(based on the screen)). **But somehow, the icon appears blurry**.

**What went wrong here  !?**

Meanwhile, I tried putting an icon with much higher pixels(512 x 512 PX) in the HDPI folder and it renders with high quality.

The only confusion is - **Despite filling out all the pixels contained in 40 DP on an HDPI display, how an image with more pixels(512) has better quality?**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/nameOfImage"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should setup a parameter in Sketchup

check:
on mac /sketchup/preference/opengl/show maximum size of texture

on pc /menu/windows/preference/opengl/show maximum size of texture